# Relative path in ANTLR tokenVocab

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR, making progress, and hit this issue.

I have a structure like so:

```
-- MAIN
---|__ SUB
       |__ ABCLexer.g4
       |__ ABCParser.g4
   BaseLexer.g4
```

I would like to use BaseLexer inside of ABCParser. So, I have tried numerous things such as:

```
options {tokenVocab=BaseLexer;}
options {tokenVocab='../BaseLexer';}
options {tokenVocab='fullpath to BaseLexer';}
```

I also tried with import to see if I could get that to work. All to no avail. Before I pull everything back into the same directory, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: 2 additional pieces of info: 1) this is Windows, 2) I am trying to use Mike's awesome ANTLR plugin in VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use paths in the import statements but instead specify a grammar search path in the tool invocation as described in the [tool-options](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md#-lib-libdir) document:

> $ antlr4 -lib /tmp A.g4

In the ANTLR4 extension for vscode you would instead provide this info in the extension settings as [described in the documentation](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/extension-settings.md#general) (see `importDir` setting).